# "In Gruppen" or "Gruppenweise"

Tags: grammar, style

> Sie helfen einander in Gruppen.
>
> Sie helfen einander gruppenweise.

They help each other in groups.

Can "in groups" be substituted by gruppenweise? My book said gruppenweise means "in groups" and I dont know if it's going to fit in this sentence. Any suggestions?

Comment: My understanding of the ENglish sentence is that it is ambiguous. Is help performed by grouped up individuals or is help performed by individuals within a group. I am not a native speaker so maybe it is clear ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Gruppenweise* means 'group by group', as opposed to *einzeln*, meaning each for themselves. That would generally mean each group helping another group. If what you mean is 'they're in groups and members of groups help other members of the same group' (clumsy as that may be), the correct term is *in Gruppen*.